# Update R package version on OpenCPU

Tags: git, github, rstudio, opencpu

I committed and pushed the updates of the R function on GitHub. However, when I check this function on OpenCPU it remains of the old version.

```
https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/Klausos9/test/R/test/print
```

I tried to re-run the command

```
install_github("Klausos9/test")
```

from RStudio, but still the changes are not uploaded to OpenCPU. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you install the webhook in your github repo? https://www.opencpu.org/api.html#api-ci

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks, I've just installed Webhook in my repository. Now as you can see I have test.R and test2.R in R folder of the package: https://github.com/Klausos9/test/tree/master/R I runned install_github("Klausos9/test") from RStudio, but again only "test.R" is visible on OpenCPU. What did I miss? https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/Klausos9/test/R/  The expected result was that I can run https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/Klausos9/test/R/test2